# How Can I make this mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to build a login system. But have a problem when I am creating the query for it. I will briefly explain what I need is. I have got `username` and `password` form login form. Now  I need to check those values with my login table weather those are exist or not in the table. As well as I need to check users' registration is expired or not in the same query using `tutors , institutes and students` tables. students registration is not expiring. Further I need to check their profile is activated or not using `active` column in tutors and institutes tables. Again students table doesn't have a column '`active`'. They don't need to activate their profile.

These are columns which I need to get from query.

```
login_id // From login table
username // From login table
login_type // From login table
date-expire true or false // From tutors or institute or student.
```

I tried it something like this but confusing in how to attach all my tables together in the same query.

```
$q = "SELECT login_id, username, login_type, IF(date_expires >= NOW(), true, false) 
        FROM login
        INNER JOIN tutors ON login.login_id = tutors.login_id
        INNER JOIN institutes ON login.login_id = institutes.login_id
        WHERE (username='$username' AND password='"  .  get_password_hash($password) .  "' 
                AND (tutors.active IS NULL || institutes.active IS NULL))";
```

But this query is not working. Can anybody tell me what is the mistake I have done?

This is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE login (
login_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
password VARBINARY(32) NOT NULL,
login_type ENUM('tutor', 'institute', 'student') NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (login_id)
)


CREATE TABLE institutes (
institute_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
login_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
active CHAR(32),
date_expires DATE NOT NULL,
date_registered TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (institute_id)
)   

CREATE TABLE tutors (
tutor_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
login_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
active CHAR(32),
date_expires DATE NOT NULL,
date_registered TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (tutor_id)
)

CREATE TABLE students (
student_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
login_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
date_registered TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
)
```

Comment: Sometimes it can help to take the SQL and create a view.  Can you craft a view to show per row all that you need to return?  Might just remove the fog.  As for defining 'status' of a user you might want to use a bit mask to define all these 'flags' in a single value.  There are pros and cons to that approach though.

Comment: @ficuscr Your comment exactly not clear for me. I don't have any experience in creating views in sql

Comment: What backend?  MySQL?  Does the SQL you are using now give any errors?  (Try running it directly in whatever tool you use or command line).  As for views, they just mask the underlying SQL.  Can help as a facade to sort of mask the complexity of a statement and make it more useful.

Comment: Is there a necessity to Check all the conditions in the `single Query` ? Alternatively you can Split the Checks and Perform them in a Sequential way or Using some 'If this then that' , making it Simple to Debug.

Comment: Ankit's point is very relevant if you expect to return a descriptive error message.  i.e. your account is not active vs. unknown user name/password.

Comment: @ficuscr Yes I tried it with command line and get this error..Column 'date_expires' in field list is ambiguous. No idea how to fix this.

Comment: Means the column exists on both tables and you are there for not uniquely identifying it.  Prefix the `tablename.tothecolumn`.

Comment: @TharangaNuwan that is because your date_expires should be tutor.date_expires or institution.date_expires. Just like ficuscr has pointed out.

Comment: @ficuscr I understand the need to return a Error Message. But it does not implies that you have to check everything in single Query, instead it would be a better approach to use dedicated queries performing limited/single task, i.e. first Check for username/password, if correct then check expiry etc. and so on. Wouldn't it be a more robust approach, or am I missing something ?

Comment: @Ankit, at risk of going off topic, I need data from 4 tables I use joins, I don't write 4 SQL statements.  There is overhead there.  Fewer calls to DB the better as far as I am concerned.  Why I love things like [Identity Maps](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html), low hanging fruit for optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

```
$q = "SELECT l.login_id, l.username, l.login_type, t.date_expires
FROM login AS l
INNER JOIN tutors AS t ON l.login_id = t.login_id
WHERE l.username='$username' AND l.password='" . get_password_hash($password) . "'
AND t.date_expires >= NOW()
AND t.active IS NULL";
```

I have split up your query. This is just the start of what could be the answer to your question. I'm still not clear about all the requirement you need.

If you could post some sample data with the required output I will be able to help you further.

Comment: when query run it outputted an empty set. But I am providing correct username and password

Comment: I would avoid using the spaces surrounding your inputed variables. If you add unintentional spaces it might give problems

Comment: I need to store username, login_type on session after users successfully login to the system.

Comment: in the mean time.. need to check their registration is expired or not to limit to access their control panel

Comment: Oke, but this is a select query. That will work for the session, but if you want to store data will require update.

Comment: I suggest we start with a working select query. Have you tried typing in the password and username? And see if that works? Perhaps via the command line or phpmyadmin or some similar program.

Comment: Thanks. But query not return any row. I am using actual usernames and passwords.

Comment: I have re-edited my answer. I have omitted everything related to institutions.

Comment: Oke I am working on an example in sql fiddle. If you give me a few minutes.

Comment: What text do you use in active? Might it be easer to use ENUM 'active' or 'not active' or an interger